# Best practice for form submission with Marionette js and Web API 2

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api2, marionette

Web API 2 has parameter binding.  Marionette has models.  How do I connect the two (e.g., make a successful form submission) in the most efficient way?

Here is my failed attempt:

```
    var attributes = $('#myForm').serialize();

    this.model.save(attributes, {
        success: function (model, response) {
            console.log('success! ' + response);
        },
        error: function (model, response) {
            console.log('error! ' + response);
        }
    });
```

No errors, but no values passed to my Web API controller either.  I see values in attributes before the save.  But no Web API parameter binding happens at the server.

A standard ajax submission, however, does work:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myresturl',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

I thought models were just ajax under the hood?  Should I not use the model for submission (save)?  What's the correct approach?